# Add a class to custom Widget input field

Tags: widget

There is a nice little feature when you add form fields to the system configuration where you can use:

```
<my_field>
    ...
    <validate>some-class</validate>
    ...
</my_field>
```

This will add a class to your `<input>` form field which is useful for all sorts of things. Is there a method to do the same when declaring a widget parameter in `widget.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

I scoured through Magento source, and I did not find where an additional value would be set in `widget.xml`. While it's a bit annoying, I resorted to using my own `<type>`.

My `widget.xml` contains:

```
<my_param translate="label">
    <required>1</required>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <label>My Label</label>
    <type>module/my_custom_block</type>
</my_param>
```

The annoying part is that my block class only contains:

```
class Module_Name_Block_My_Custom_Block extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $element->addClass('my-class');
        $this->_element = $element;
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: Old old question, but I ran into this recently. I didn't find a way to do this and your solution seems like the only _proper_ way to go about it. However, there IS the `setFrameTags($open, $close = null)` method. Which would technically make it possible to do something like `setFrameTags('input class="foo"')` but it's nasty.